# Vector field whose rotation is normal to a half ellipsoid

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, ellipsoids

I have a (special) half ellipsoid
$$\tilde F=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}\ \bigg|\ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1,\ z\geq0\right\}$$
and need a vector field $f$ whose rotation is normal to that surface, so something like
$$\begin{cases}\partial_yf_z-\partial_zf_y=\frac{x}{a^2}\\\partial_zf_x-\partial_xf_z=\frac{y}{a^2}\\\partial_xf_y-\partial_yf_x=\frac{z}{b^2}\end{cases}\qquad\forall (x,y,z)\in\tilde F $$
However, I'm not sure if something like this is even possible.

---

In case you're wondering *why* I want this: I want to determine the surface area of the (full) ellipsoid
$$F=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}\ \bigg|\ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1\right\}$$
Therefore I want to use the half ellipsoid, so
$$v_2(F)=2v_2(\tilde F)$$
$\tilde F$ then is a compact subset of the submanifold $F$ with a *smooth boundary* (I'm not sure I translated this correctly from the german *glatter Rand*)
$$\partial\tilde F=\left\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^3\ \bigg|\ x^2+y^2=a^2\right\}$$
So one can apply the Kelvin–Stokes theorem
$$\int_{\partial\tilde F}\langle f,d\vec s\rangle=\int_{\tilde F}\langle\mathrm{rot} f(x),\nu(x)\rangle dS(x)$$
Which looks similar to the surface I'm looking for,
$$v_2(\tilde F)=\int_{\tilde F}dS(x)$$
So I merely have to achieve that $\langle\mathrm{rot} f(x),\nu(x)\rangle=1$ (and then calculate the line integral of the boundary). As $\nu$ is the normalized normal field to the ellipsoid, I can achieve this by requiring $\mathrm{rot} f(x)=\nu(x)$ - which leads to this question.

---

It's kind of hard to explain (and draw) what I mean, but my idea was to modify $\nu$ outside of $\tilde F$ in a way, that the divergence is $0$, by letting the flow run in from the bottom - drawn in two dimensions:
[image: plot of the flow]
If $\nu$ then is normed (such that $\|\nu(x)\|=1\ \forall x$) the divergence *should* be $0$ (right?).

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Edjk/18_022/chapter08/section03.html) post here: for a fixed vector field $\mathbf{v}$ in a simply connected region $R$, we can find a vector field $\mathbf A$ such that $\mathbf v = \nabla \times \mathbf A$ if and only if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf v = 0$ in $R$.

Unfortunately, in this case the divergence
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf v = (1/a^2) + (1/a^2) + (1/b^2) $$
is never zero.

Comment: But I only need the _half_ ellipsoid - couldn't the divergence be 0, if (roughly spoken) the flow that escapes the half ellipsoid comes in at the bottom?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you elaborate? 
All I'm claiming is that the divergence of the normal vector field is a positive constant function, so by the cited result it can't be the curl of another vector field defined on the same region.

Comment: My $\nu$ is only the normal vector field on the surface of the half ellipsoid - not including the base with $z=0$. So if one imagines $\nu$ to _flow_ in at the bottom and (perpendicularly) out at the sides of the half ellipsoid, its divergence would be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: I see. So you're taking the region where $v$ is defined to be the upper half of the ellipse, where I'm thinking of $v$ as being defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$. However, the upper half of the ellipse is still a simply-connected region, so the result should still apply no?

Comment: You are probably right

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having trouble understanding your intuitive argument, so maybe someone else can connect the two. Anyway, I thought your post was interesting and showed good research effort--thanks for sharing your approach to calculating the surface area of the ellipsoid.

Comment: I've editted my question to try to explain my idea. I _think_ it should be possible that the divergence is $0$ on $F$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119165/discussion-between-sam-freedman-and-metacolon).